# How to loop to find equal words

Tags: java

I have 1 array list and I want to loop through that array list to find words that are the same within that array list because I need to store that index number where they are the same somewhere. So I wrote this code below to help me get started:

```
String[] word = new String[] { "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop" };
String[] word2 = new String[] { "ijkl", "rstu", "mnop" };

int totalWords = word.length;
int totalWords2 = word2.length;

//Use a List instead of array, because you don't know how many unique there are
List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < totalWords; i++) { // loop of the first array list
boolean unique = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < totalWords2; j++) { // second loop where the
                                        // words are being compared
    //compare String this way
        if (word[i].equals(word2[j])) {
        //we find two equals strings, it is unique
            unique = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (unique) {
        uniqueWords.add(word[i]);
    }
}

for (String s : uniqueWords) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

and it works and prints

```
ijkl 
mnop
```

Now I took this same code and I applied it to my problem and got the following but it doesn't work. It just prints out my exact array list. I just care about storing the index number where there are equal words in the list but it doesn't print correctly so I can't store anything yet. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

```
//signatureList is my array list that i want to loop through to find words that are equal with each other
int o = signatureList.size();

      //Use a List instead of array, because you don't know how many unique there are
      List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i = 0; i < o; i++) { // loop of the first array list
          boolean unique = false;

          for (int j = 1; j < o; j++) { // second loop where the
                                                  // words are being compared
              //compare String this way
              if (signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j))) {
                  //we find two equals strings, it is unique
                  unique = true;
                  break;
              }
          }


          if (unique) {
              uniqueWords.add(signatureList.get(i));
          }
      }

//prints out uniqueWords array list
      for(int i = 0; i < o ; i++)
            System.out.println("words that are equal " + uniqueWords.get(i));
```

Comment: Why don't you try debugging your code?

Comment: Your code don't search for all equals words, just find one and stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> signatureList = new ArrayList<String>();
    signatureList.add("Test");
    signatureList.add("asdf");
    signatureList.add("jkjk");
    signatureList.add("Test");
    signatureList.add("1231");
    signatureList.add("asdf");
    signatureList.add("Test");

    Map<String,List<Integer>> locations = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < signatureList.size(); i++) { 
        boolean unique = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < signatureList.size(); j++) {

            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }

            if (signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j))) {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (!unique) {

            if(locations.containsKey(signatureList.get(i))){
                List<Integer> intLocations = locations.get(signatureList.get(i));
                intLocations.add(i);
                locations.put(signatureList.get(i), intLocations);
            }else{
                List<Integer> intLocations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                intLocations.add(i);
                locations.put(signatureList.get(i), intLocations);
            }
        }
    }

    for(Entry<String,List<Integer>> en : locations.entrySet()){
        System.out.print(en.getKey() + " : ");
        for(Integer i : en.getValue()){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Gives me output:

```
Test : 0 3 6 
asdf : 1 5
```

Full source for example and testing. Make sure to skip comparing to itself, and do not add to the list if it is already in the list.

Updated my answer to contain a solution for finding the indexes where the matches reside at.

Comment: how do you think I can save the original indexes where the equal words were in the signatureList? For example in your example the word "Test" are equal at index 0 and 3, and "asdf" are equal at index 1 and 5. How can i store these indexes? Im guessing it should be within that if statement before the for loop that prints the same words out but its tricky

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution for your comment. Use a hashmap to store a list of integers for the locations. The key should be your string, and the value is a list of all indexes that the key appeared at. Everytime it is a match, you add that index to the list in the map

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the index, think of doing this and instead of using a boolean to determine that it's unique just add the index to the arraylist, getting rid of the unnecessary if statement, especially since it isn't even in the correct for loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> uniqueWordsIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j))) {
              //we find two equals strings, it is unique
              uniqueWordsIndex.add(i)
              break;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < o; i++) { 
      boolean unique = false;

      for (int j = 1; j < o; j++) { 

          if (signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j))) {// the culprit is here
              //we find two equals strings, it is unique
              unique = true;
              break;
          }
      }
```

The above code is giving you problems. signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j) will be true atleast one time for all the elements of signatureList. So , all elements are added to your unique List.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different issues:
First is that you need to not do this check if `i == j`, so do it only when they are different.  You can keep the equals check, just have unique be a number, and set it to zero instead of false, then increment that value. If `unique > 1` then add it to your list as you found a duplicate.

Also, get rid of an unnessary check on `unique`.

```
          if (signatureList.get(i).equals(signatureList.get(j))) {
              //we find two equals strings, it is unique
              unique = true;
              uniqueWords.add(signatureList.get(i));
              break;
          }
```

In this for loop, `o` wasn't set to the length of the unique list, so you will get an error when your problem is fixed.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < o ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more problem additionally to the comments:

You must only compare two words if they have a different index. If you compare words with the same index (i = j), of course all of them will be included in the result.